# AddOrUpdate method in ConcurrentDictionary thread safe alternative

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrentdictionary

As per this link [Is AddOrUpdate thread safe in ConcurrentDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156752/is-addorupdate-thread-safe-in-concurrentdictionary) from the "Remarks" section on this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx. it says

> "However, delegates for these methods are called outside the locks to
> avoid the problems that can arise from executing unknown code under a
> lock. Therefore, the code executed by these delegates is not subject
> to the atomicity of the operation."

The issue is I extensively use this throughout my code and realize i have a potential very nasty bug (my understanding has been wrong all along)... since in the way I use the below I did not expect the delegates could be called at the same time and overwrite the internal dictionary:

```
internal class HandlerProducers
{
    readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, InstanceProducer>> handlerProducers
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, InstanceProducer>>();

    public void AddProducer(Type notificationType, Type concreteType, InstanceProducer producer)
    {
        this.handlerProducers
                .AddOrUpdate(
                    notificationType,
                    (key) => new Dictionary<Type, InstanceProducer> { { concreteType, producer } },
                    (key, dictionary) => { dictionary.Add(concreteType, producer); return dictionary; });
    }

    public IEnumerable<InstanceProducer> GetForHandler(Type notificationHandlerType)
    {
        if(this.handlerProducers.TryGetValue(notificationHandlerType, out var dict))
        {
            foreach (var kvp in dict)
                yield return kvp.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a further challenge that naively putting locks in place will potentially cause a hot spot, the above class is used extensively for reading from via `GetForHandler()` and is written to occasionally (via the `AddProducer()` method.

**What would be the best way to ensure this is thread safe by design by performant with massive reads and occasional writes?**

Comment: As I mentioned in your other question, the simplest you can do is to leave `AddOrUpdate` and use `TryAdd` together with `TryUpdate` - those are thread-safe and don't require much change

Comment: Thanks Camilo, you opened my eyes to a nasty bug. I will update my previous question as that is a different use case (similair problem from my misunderstanding but may need to solve with a delayed subscribe I will explain there) and try to answer this one with tryadd as you kindly recommend

Comment: It is only an issue if you do something thread-unsafe in the lambda expressions.  Like using handlerProducers.  No issue here, posted code is safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use a nested `ConcurrentDictionary` structure:

```
readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConcurrentDictionary<Type, InstanceProducer>> handlerProducers
    = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConcurrentDictionary<Type, InstanceProducer>>();
```

You could then implement the `AddProducer` method like this:

```
public void AddProducer(Type notificationType, Type concreteType,
    InstanceProducer producer)
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<Type, InstanceProducer> innerDict =
        this.handlerProducers.GetOrAdd(notificationType,
            _ => new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, InstanceProducer>());

    if (!innerDict.TryAdd(concreteType, producer))
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            $"{notificationType}.{concreteType} already exists.");
}
```

The method `GetForHandler` needs no modification.

This implementation will make your `HandlerProducers` class truly thread-safe, without sacrificing its efficiency.