# How is a null value getting into my concurrent dictionary?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

I have a simple connection manager service in my web app that keeps track of websocket connections against a user GUID they are associated with. These are stored in a dictionary with the key being a user GUID and the value being a list of connection IDs (both strings).

```
ConnectionsByUser = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

I have a register connection function as below:

```
public void RegisterConnection(string userGuid, string connectionId)
{
    if (connectionId == null)
    {
        logger.LogError($"Null connection id found for user {userGuid}");
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionId));
    }

    ConnectionsByUser.AddOrUpdate(userGuid, new List<string>() { connectionId }, (key, value) =>
    {
        value.Add(connectionId);
        return value;
    });
}
```

I also have an unregister function:

```
public void UnregisterConnection(string connectionId)
{
    foreach (var user in ConnectionsByUser)
    {
        if (user.Value.Contains(connectionId))
        {
            user.Value.Remove(connectionId);
        }

        if (!user.Value.Any())
        {
            ConnectionsByUser.TryRemove(user.Key, out var _);
        }
    } 
}
```

Finally I have a Get function:

```
public List<string> GetConnectionIdsByUserGuid(string userGuid)
{
    var hasValue = ConnectionsByUser.TryGetValue(userGuid, out var connectionIds);

    if (!hasValue)
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }

    return connectionIds;
}
```

These are the **only** references to the `ConnectionsByUser` dictionary, yet somehow we have instances where `GetConnectionIdsByUserGuid` returns a list containing a null value mixed in with other actual valid connection IDs.

Considering that register function has a null check, I am clueless to how a null value gets into the list, at this point I assume that there is something about the way concurrent dictionary is implemented that I do not understand.

Comment: The `ConcurrentDictionary` is threadsafe, but the list you are updating in it IS NOT.

Comment: Related: [Is AddOrUpdate thread safe in ConcurrentDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156752/is-addorupdate-thread-safe-in-concurrentdictionary)

Answer (score 0):

The [`ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2) collection is safe when both the keys and the values are immutable. When the values are mutable, trying to make it safe becomes a pain in the neck, assuming that it's possible to do it at all.

My suggestion is to switch from a mutable [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) to an immutable [`ImmutableHashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablehashset-1), as the container of each user's connections. Here is an example of how you could do it:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, ImmutableHashSet<string>> ConnectionsByUser = new();

public void RegisterConnection(string userGuid, string connectionId)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(userGuid);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(connectionId);

    ConnectionsByUser.AddOrUpdate(userGuid,
        (_, value) => ImmutableHashSet<string>.Empty.Add(value),
        (_, existingConnections, value) => existingConnections.Add(value),
        connectionId);
}

public bool UnregisterConnection(string userGuid, string connectionId)
{
    while (ConnectionsByUser.TryGetValue(userGuid, out var existingConnections))
    {
        var updatedConnections = existingConnections.Remove(connectionId);
        if (ReferenceEquals(updatedConnections, existingConnections))
        {
            return false; // Connection not found
        }
        else if (updatedConnections.IsEmpty)
        {
            if (ConnectionsByUser.TryRemove(
                KeyValuePair.Create(userGuid, existingConnections)))
                    return true; // Connection found and removed. User removed.
        }
        else
        {
            if (ConnectionsByUser.TryUpdate(
                userGuid, updatedConnections, existingConnections))
                    return true; // Connection found and removed.
        }
        // We lost the race to update the dictionary. Try again.
    }
    return false; // User not found
}

public IReadOnlyCollection<string> GetConnectionIdsByUserGuid(string userGuid)
{
    return ConnectionsByUser.TryGetValue(userGuid, out var connectionIds) ?
        connectionIds : ImmutableHashSet<string>.Empty;
}
```

I changed the signature of the `UnregisterConnection` method so that it has a `userGuid` parameter, otherwise searching blindly for a `connectionId` to remove will be very inefficient.

In the above example, all three methods (`RegisterConnection`, `UnregisterConnection` and `GetConnectionIdsByUserGuid`) are atomic. No possible sequence of events exists that could bring the dictionary in a corrupted state.

The `GetConnectionIdsByUserGuid` returns a snapshot of the user's connections that were stored in the dictionary, at the time that the method was called. The returned object does not represent a dynamically updated list of the connections, as they evolve over time.